# How get large size album pictures of facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook graph api, that I am using to login user, User allow permission for user_photos and graph api getting list of albums, then get list of pictures by album id, but pictures are of thumbnail size 130x130. Please anybody give some code hint to get large image of album's upload pictures.

following code I am using to access albums and pictures

```
$albums = $fb->get('/me/albums', $accessToken)->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
foreach( $albums as $album_id => $album_data ){
    $fbPictures = $fb->get("/".$album_data['id']."/photos?fields=picture&limit=12&type=normal", $accessToken)->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
}
```

$fbPictures variable getting arrays of pictures of album, that has picture id and URL of small thumbnail, but i can't access the large size image. Please guide me how that is possible?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you looking for URLs of _every_ image in _every_ album? Or just the album cover photo of all the users albums?

Comment: I am looking for every image in each album created by user that is logged-in by facebook on my website

Comment: Since _every_ image is in an album, you could use the [/photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/) node on the user. Using `?type=uploaded` will give you a list of all of the logged-in users uploaded photos. Does that seem like it does what you need?

Comment: Check the `images` property of the photo object. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo

Comment: Thanks CBroe, your guideline went straight on target. I used $fbPictures = $fb->get("/".$album_data['id']."/photos?fields=images&limit=12", $accessToken)->getGraphEdge()->asArray();  and it works very well.